# HTTP Live Streaming not working with GStreamer

Tags: java, jetty, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I am trying to create a live stream over HTTP using GStreamer. I used the following command for the HLS sink:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true pattern=snow ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5
```

There are no errors or warnings. The generated `ts` and `m3u8` files are located in `src/main/resources/videos`. This folder is part of a Maven project that also contains a Jetty server. Here is the main class:

```
public class Main {
    private static final int PORT = 1778;
    private static final String RESOURCE_BASE = "./src/main/resources";
    private static final String WELCOME_FILE = "index.html";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Server jettyServer = new Server(PORT);

        final ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();

        resourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
        resourceHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{WELCOME_FILE});
        resourceHandler.setResourceBase(RESOURCE_BASE);

        final HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resourceHandler, new DefaultHandler() });
        jettyServer.setHandler(handlers);

        try {
            jettyServer.start();
            jettyServer.join();
        } finally {
            jettyServer.stop();
            jettyServer.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `src/main/resources/index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <video src="./videos/playlist.m3u8" controls="" autoplay="" width="960" height="540"></video>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I start the server, I get the following screen on Safari (the picture does not change):
[image: HTTP Live Streaming Screen on Safari]
The `ts` files are correctly generated and `playlist.m3u8` is being found successfully (the player gives an error otherwise). Why am I not getting a live stream of the default snow pattern?

In case it is relevant, I am running this on `OS X Yosemite 10.10.5` and the Safari version is `Version 10.1 (10603.1.30.0.34)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try forcing a specific H.264 profile. If you don't do that `videotestsrc` and `x264enc` may agree on a format not supported by the decoder.

```
... x264enc ! video/x-h264, profile=main ! mpegtsmux ...
```